# How to print text output in r markdown

Tags: r-markdown

Does anyone know how to display text output into an R markdown file? I haven't seen any tutorial cover what I want to do, which is take input from a shiny app and use that for a for loop in my code which will create a text document, which is what I want to display. I don't want to write all of the code I have because it is quite long and isn't necessary, but can anybody at least point me in the write direction?

Comment: This is a pretty good question. I did that a few years ago, I needed output in PDF format. I combined rmarkdown and a `for` loop. Last step of that writing loop was `writelines(c(x,y,etc))` where x... stands for various variables formatted in the first part of the loop.  When you knit the rmarkdown file writelines stdout gets written as intermediary markdown and converted in the target format you desire. If need be I can find the code, but I gather you have done something as well.